# Select values that are the same in another column in another layer

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select

I'm working n QGIS 3.10.7-A Coruña. I have two layers: point.shp (670 features) and line.shp (4500 features). Both of them have a column called "code" with string values. I want to select from line.shp the 670 features that are the same in column "code" for both layers (so they exist in point.shp)
I need to select by expression as far as I understand. How can I reference a column in a different layer? What should be the expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `aggregate()` function in QGIS is both ridiculously powerful and also difficult to understand, but it's exactly what you need.

Conceptually this is what we're going to do:

- First you need to create a list (an array in this case) of all the "code" values that appear in point.shp
- Then you're going to have the Select By Expression tool check if that array contains the "code" value for each feature in line.shp

So select line.shp and open Select By Expression, and use the following expression:

`array_contains(aggregate('point', 'array_agg', "code"), "code")`

That should return what you're looking for.

If you want to understand that more then first just add this piece in the middle:

`aggregate('point', 'array_agg', "code")`

You will see the Preview at the bottom of the dialogue returns the array of the code values. It really helps if you find the `aggregate` function in the list of functions and then write the expression out manually while looking at the documentation on the right:
[image]

That will help you to understand what each part of the expression is doing. Then you can do the same for the `array_contains` part of the expression.

Good luck!

Comment: for large layers, it would be beneficial to filter the values before aggregating them (`"code"= attribute(@parent,'code')`)

Comment: @JGH good idea, where would that fit into the expression I wrote? I'm just about at the limits of my ability haha

Comment: The filter would be in the `aggregate` call, so the complete call would be `array_contains(aggregate('point', 'array_agg', "code","code"= attribute(@parent,'code')), "code")`